# How to update an XYZ layer in Open Layers 5

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

Is removing and re-adding an XYZ layer the only way to update it in ol5?

I know TileWMS has an `updateParams()` method, which is nice, but some of the layers I'm working with are XYZ with a time query parameter.

Here is the pseudo code for how I've worked around it, but it doesn't seem like the right way to go about it.

```js
function createLayer() {
    return new TileLayer({
        source: new XYZ({
            url: 'https://url?x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&time=' + dateTimeString,
        })
    });
}
map.addLayer(createLayer());
// user interaction to change the time
map.removeLayer(createLayer());
map.addLayer(createLayer());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method can be used either as a dummy parameter to override caching or to set a configurable time parameter on sources such as weather maps:

```
var layer = new TileLayer({
            source: new XYZ()
        });
function setTileUrl(dateTime) {
    layer.getSource().setUrl('https://url?x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&time=' + dateTime);
}
setTileUrl(initialDateTime);
map.addLayer(layer);
// user interaction to change the time
setTileUrl(newDateTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to refresh the source in connection with using a tileUrlFunction:

```
TileLayer.getSource().refresh();
```

See also [here.](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Source-Source.html#refresh)

Comment: That would only clear the Openlayers cache, it won't re-evaluate the url.   `TileLayer.getSource().setUrl('https://url?x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&time=' + dateTimeString);` will do both (the time parameter will still be needed to override the browser cache).

Comment: You are right. In connection with a tileUrlFunction it works for me.